# How to sort a LinkedList of Float arrays by the first index in each array?

Tags: java, linked-list

Suppose that I have a linked list of Float arrays,

`LinkedList<Float[]> foo = new LinkedList<Float[]>();
foo.add(new Float[] {2.3, 2.4});
foo.add(new Float[] {1.0, 3.2});
foo.add(new Float[] {1.5, 3.5});`

I want to sort this LinkedList by the first element of each float array in each node (2.3, 1.0, and 1.5).

For this example, after sorting, the first node would contain the array `{1.0, 3.2}`, the next would have the array `{1.5, 3.5}`, and the last node would contain `{2.3, 2.4}`.

Comment: Create a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that takes two such Float arrays and compares them according to the first item. Then pass your LinkedList with the comparator to [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom `Comparator<Float[]>` that compares the first elements. Something like `(a,b)->Float.compare(a[0],b[0])`.

Then use [`Collections.sort(List<Float[]>,Comparator<Float>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to sort your array.

Comment: Comparable should be Comparator.

Comment: You probably want a `Float[]` there.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that too.